# Working Android app got unstable

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I created an android app that had a feature to add a profile and edit it . Everything was working fine for all these days , but suddenly today morning every-time I tried to save changes after editing a profile , it started to stop responding and quit .

I captured the error using crash-mail and here is what I got :

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.4.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=SHV-E300L
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
at com.diwesh.Ecgapp.adapter.AdapterProfileList.getView(AdapterProfileList.java:78)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2720)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2533)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15656)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4857)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15656)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4857)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15656)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4857)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15656)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4857)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15656)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4857)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2288)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2008)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1238)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6473)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AdapterList.java

```
package com.diwesh.Ecgapp.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.R;
import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.db.ProfileDBManager.ProfileModel;
import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.doc.Globals;
import com.pkmmte.circularimageview.CircularImageView;


public class AdapterProfileList extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<ProfileModel> m_lstItems;    
    public int selItem = -1;
    public Context con;
//    private SwipeDetector swipeDetector;

    public AdapterProfileList(Context con)
    {
        super();
        this.con = con;
//        swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (this.m_lstItems == null)
            return 0;
        return this.m_lstItems.size();
    }

    public ProfileModel getItem(int paramInt)
    {
        return this.m_lstItems.get(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt)
    {
        return 0L;
    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
    {
        View localView = paramView;
        ViewHolder localViewHolder = null;

        if (localView == null)
        {
            localView = LayoutInflater.from(paramViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_profile, null);
        }
        else
        {
            localViewHolder = (ViewHolder) localView.getTag();
        }
        if (localViewHolder == null){
            localViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            localViewHolder.m_item1 = ((CircularImageView)localView.findViewById(R.id.imgDoge));
            localViewHolder.m_item2 = ((TextView)localView.findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_item)); 
            localViewHolder.ll_swipe = ((LinearLayout)localView.findViewById(R.id.ll_profile));

            localView.setTag(localViewHolder);
        }

//        localViewHolder.ll_swipe.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
        //add String
        final ProfileModel t = m_lstItems.get(paramInt);
        //localViewHolder.m_item1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(t.image));
        Bitmap bm = Globals.setImageScale(con, Uri.parse(t.image));
        localViewHolder.m_item1.setImageBitmap(bm);        
        String ss = t.firstName +  " " + t.lastName + " " + t.age +"years old";
        if (t.gender == 0)
        {
            ss = ss + " Male";
        }
        else
        {
            ss = ss + " Female";
        }
        localViewHolder.m_item2.setText(ss);    


        return localView;
    }

    public void update(List<ProfileModel> paramList)
    {
        this.m_lstItems = paramList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public CircularImageView m_item1;
        public TextView m_item2;      
        public LinearLayout ll_swipe;
    }

    public void remove(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("LIST ITEMSL::", ""+m_lstItems);
        Log.e("mLIST ITEM SIZE::"+m_lstItems.size(), "ID>>>>"+id);
        m_lstItems.remove(m_lstItems.get(id));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

Please help .....

Edit 1 : Added null check as suggested : App does not crash now on relaunch but still crashes when I click the Profile tab after editing it once again . Here is the new logcat

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.4.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=SHV-E300L
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
at com.diwesh.Ecgapp.ui.Fragment3.setData(Fragment3.java:149)
at com.diwesh.Ecgapp.ui.Fragment3.initControl(Fragment3.java:142)
at com.diwesh.Ecgapp.ui.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:75)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New AdapterList.java after changes

```
package com.diwesh.Ecgapp.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.R;
import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.db.ProfileDBManager.ProfileModel;
import com.diwesh.Ecgapp.doc.Globals;
import com.pkmmte.circularimageview.CircularImageView;


public class AdapterProfileList extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<ProfileModel> m_lstItems;    
    public int selItem = -1;
    public Context con;
//    private SwipeDetector swipeDetector;

    public AdapterProfileList(Context con)
    {
        super();
        this.con = con;
//        swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (this.m_lstItems == null)
            return 0;
        return this.m_lstItems.size();
    }

    public ProfileModel getItem(int paramInt)
    {
        return this.m_lstItems.get(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt)
    {
        return 0L;
    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
    {
        View localView = paramView;
        ViewHolder localViewHolder = null;

        if (localView == null)
        {
            localView = LayoutInflater.from(paramViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_profile, null);
        }
        else
        {
            localViewHolder = (ViewHolder) localView.getTag();
        }
        if (localViewHolder == null){
            localViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            localViewHolder.m_item1 = ((CircularImageView)localView.findViewById(R.id.imgDoge));
            localViewHolder.m_item2 = ((TextView)localView.findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_item)); 
            localViewHolder.ll_swipe = ((LinearLayout)localView.findViewById(R.id.ll_profile));

            localView.setTag(localViewHolder);
        }

//        localViewHolder.ll_swipe.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
        //add String
        final ProfileModel t = m_lstItems.get(paramInt);
        //localViewHolder.m_item1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(t.image));

        if(t.image != null) // added this to prevent crash mail
        {
        Bitmap bm = Globals.setImageScale(con, Uri.parse(t.image));
        localViewHolder.m_item1.setImageBitmap(bm);     
        }
        String ss = t.firstName +  " " + t.lastName + " " + t.age +"years old";
        if (t.gender == 0)
        {
            ss = ss + " Male";
        }
        else
        {
            ss = ss + " Female";
        }
        localViewHolder.m_item2.setText(ss);    


        return localView;
    }

    public void update(List<ProfileModel> paramList)
    {
        this.m_lstItems = paramList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public CircularImageView m_item1;
        public TextView m_item2;      
        public LinearLayout ll_swipe;
    }

    public void remove(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("LIST ITEMSL::", ""+m_lstItems);
        Log.e("mLIST ITEM SIZE::"+m_lstItems.size(), "ID>>>>"+id);
        m_lstItems.remove(m_lstItems.get(id));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code including AdapterProfileList

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace you are getting a null uriString (obviously).

You should have a null checker whenever there's a possibility of having a null value.

Without further information about your problem, this is all we can recommend you.

Comment: But what could possible trigger the null value ? I mean I am filling in all the possible fields and am also changing the values from old to new . What i have noticed is that when I click this save button after editing , it says "Changes saved" but the app crashes when I hit the back button to go to the previous screen. The app keeps on failing to even start after that. Also This was all working on the same app . But just in the morning suddenly stopped working.

Comment: `t.image` is definitely null. You should trace why it's null on setting data to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your Image URI is coming `null` in this error case. For prevention, we can add Null check :

```
    if(t.image != null) {
        Bitmap bm = Globals.setImageScale(con, Uri.parse(t.image));
        localViewHolder.m_item1.setImageBitmap(bm);        
    }
```

This will solve above Fatal error

Comment: Thanks but it lead to another error ... Now the app does not crash on opening but once i edit the profile and go to profile section again ... The app crashes with a new log . I have pasted the new logcat ....

Answer (score 0):

From your log, the `t.image` is null, so causing the error.  You should check whether it is null before calling `Uri.parse()`.

As for why it happened today instead of yesterday, there are so many possibilities: maybe you have cleared the data, maybe you have updated some code you forgot you have updated it, maybe the data has been messed in other part of you app.  Please focus on tracing the code instead of "Why it won't work today".